# Allow guests to edit nodes with secret URLs, and to claim these nodes when creating user accounts

Tags: user-management, drupal

I’m looking for a Drupal module (published on drupal.org), for 7 or 8.

- When a guest creates a node, show a secret URL.
- When visiting the secret URL, that node can be edited.
- When editing the node, offer a way to create an account. Then that node should belong to the new user.

Comment: [Inline Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_registration) allows registering from within the node. Together with something like [Node authorize link](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_authlink)/[Node Edit URL](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeker/1230502) (I think there was a more popular module, too, but can’t remember its name …) it might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something tricky in your question. I.e. the "key" to be allowed to edit such node (with a secret URL), is to just guess that URL. That's like a security similar to "you name it (the secret), you got it (do whatever edits you want to apply to that node)" ... Better make the length of such secret URL ***looooooong*** enough (just ***long*** may not be sufficient). Anyway, that's what you want it seems ...

#### Part 1: Generate a random string

There is a (sandbox) module for it, which is the [Rules generate string](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mlncn/1377622) module. Here is a quote about it (from the linked page):

> A simple rule to generate a random string, given optional parameters of length and character set.
>
> Original motivation to use in Rules-based URL shortener per specification of [mitchell](https://www.drupal.org/user/68284). (If looking to create a URL shortener for external links, an alternative non-rules approach is the dedicated module [Shurly](https://www.drupal.org/project/shurly).)

Either you just use that module, or you look at its [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-mlncn-1377622/tree/) to understand what it takes to include this logic in your own (custom) module.

With that, all that's needed is to create a custom rule (using the [Rules generate string](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mlncn/1377622) module), which you can do like so like so:

- **Rules Event**: use whatever event that fits your requirements (eg: After saving a new node, optionally limited to selected Content Types only).
- **Rules Condition**: "User has role", to check if it's an anonymous user.
- **Rules Action**: Use the action provided by this module.

BTW: "sandbox" modules are also "published" on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org), right?

#### Part 2: Rules is your friend

Using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, it is, IMO, possible to address the first 2 requirements in your question (the 3rd one is a different animal, which would probably require additional modules specialized in those things). BTW, [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) is a prerequisite module (dependency) for the module in Part 1 anyway.

If you wonder how to create the appropriate rules (1 won't be sufficient ...), then I suggest you post a followup question about that at [drupal.SE](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) (which is where IMO such followup question would belong).